# How to Remove div Tags Without Attributes; While Keeping Inner HTML?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I'd like to use PHP DOM Document to remove `div` tags which do not contain any attributes. However, I'd like to be able to keep all inner HTML contents.

**Example:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="test">
            Testing...
        </div><!-- end #test -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result:**

```
<div id="test">
    Testing...
</div><!-- end #test -->
```

Here's what I was thinking, but can't seem to get this to do what I want. This method seems to be deleting everything instead of the `<div>` tags with no attributes.

```
# Remove blank div wraps
if ( $div_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'div' ) ) {

    $blank_divs = array();

    foreach ( $div_tags as $div_tag ) {

        if ( ! $div_tag->hasAttributes() ) {
            $blank_divs[] = $div_tag;
        }

    }

    if ( ! empty( $blank_divs ) ) {

        foreach ( array_reverse( $blank_divs ) as $blank_div ) {
            $blank_div->parentNode->removeChild( $blank_div );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Before you call each removeChild, insert all children of $blank_div into its parent node to immediately following $blank_div.

Comment: If you are open to using regex, this can work https://3v4l.org/EEdDR

Comment: @mega6382 [`<div >oops</div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha hahaha, fixed https://3v4l.org/eMjJ9, anyway, a disclaimer: I wouldn't ever use this in production.

Comment: @mega6382 [`< div>oops</div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6998123)

Comment: @OP, please ignore me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many iterations you need to remove, you can do the following:

```
var icount = 2; // number of iterations.
for(i=0; i<icount; i++){
    var innerElement = $("#test").contents();
    $("#test").replaceWith(innerElement );
}
```

If you don't know your itterstion you just have to have an identifiable parent such as this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div id="test">
        Testing...
    </div><!-- end #test -->
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var innerElement = $("#test").contents();
  $("#container").replaceWith(innerElement );
</script>
```

Comment: That is `jQuery` not `PHP`. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if it's still in your PHP when you get this far, is there a reason you can't just prevent the creation of the extra tags upstream?  Also, if this is an issue where those 2 sets of parent tags sometimes have stuff and sometimes don't, you may be better off to leave them there since this may make certain CSS rules easier to manage.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Out of curiosity, what makes you believe this was actually generated at all in PHP, and by OP? The DOM could have been created from a string gotten from another site. OP could be dealing with code from an external library.

Comment: That's why I asked it as a question.